# Why does `kubectl logs` only show the most recent log rows?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes pod running on Google Container Engine. It has been running for several days, writing to the log, without any restarts.

Why is the command `kubectl logs` only showing log rows from today?

Where does this limitation come from and is it based on time or number of log rows?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Logrotate is enabled by default on container engine VMs. You should be able to check conf at below location for docker container logs.

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/docker-containers
```

So when you run `kubectl logs`, it streams you from current log file. Past logs are already gzipped and also only N compressed files are available as per logrotate configuration.

You can check all containers log files at location `/var/log/containers` also sym linked to `/var/lib/docker/containers/$containerId/`

You may also want to refer to documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_logs/#options and see if additional options can come to rescue.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while looking for a similar answer while using Microk8s. For *why* this occurring, refer to @Anupam's excellent answer. The process for finding the logs on other Kubernetes flavors is pretty similar, with some exceptions.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar `logrotate` config file (Microk8s uses `containerd`, not Docker) as mentioned in @Anupam's answer, so here is a more generalized set of instructions that should work for other Kubernetes flavors.

Run this command on the container host, which will show where the current log files are linked from:

```bash
ls -l /var/log/containers
```

This produced output similar to this for me (replace `<namespace>`, `<pod>`, `<uuid>`, and `<container>` with the info for the container you're needing logs from):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 173 Sep  2 18:30 <pod>_<namespace>_<container-id>.log -> /var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod>_<uuid>/<container>/0.log
```

I used the parent folder of the link target to change directories:

```bash
cd /var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod>_<uuid>/<container>/
```

Using `ls -la` to view the contents of this directory shows the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Sep 30 22:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Sep  2 18:30 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root root  4795001 Oct  3 12:27 0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   912950 Sep 19 12:26 0.log.20220913-182655.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1058328 Sep 25 04:27 0.log.20220919-122656.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1065468 Sep 30 22:27 0.log.20220925-042706.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10490792 Sep 30 22:27 0.log.20220930-222723
```

The part of the filename following `0.log.` represents the date that the log was rotated. If you're looking for logs from September 24th, 2022, for example, you would use the following command (`zcat` is used for displaying compressed file contents):

```bash
zcat 0.log.20220925-042706.gz
```

This would then produce the logs you're looking for. Hope this helps anyone else who stumbles on this question and needs a nudge in the right direction.