# Kubernetes - increase kubectl log size

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging

I have an app running in a kubernetes managed docker container, using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I can output logs to a text file for the app deployment using:

```
kubectl logs deployment/my-deployment > out.txt
```

This gives me a file of around max 28Mb. When I get the docker logs for the same container on the physical VM using `docker logs ...`, the log file is much bigger (up to 120Mb+).

How can I increase the size of the available `kubectl logs` for the deployment? If this option is available, then it would likely be an option that increases the size of the available `kubectl logs` for the *pod* that holds the container, as the pod and deployment logs are identical.

It's not the docker configuration in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` that's limiting the `kubectl` logs, as that's set to 50Mb. I've read that it's the underlying docker configuration that kubernetes uses, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as my`kubectl` logs are being truncated to around 28Mb.

Answer (score 3):

[`Kubectl logs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) might read logs with a default log rotation, meaning the [logrotate service is active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398892/6309).

Check the content of cat /etc/logrotate.d/docker-containers, as in [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11046), for confirmation.

As explained in [`unofficial-kubernetes`](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20uses%20the%20logrotate%20tool,for%20the%20container%20are%20lost.):

> An important consideration in node-level logging is implementing log rotation, so that logs don't consume all available storage on the node. Kubernetes uses the `logrotate` tool to implement log rotation.
>
> Kubernetes performs log rotation daily, or if the log file grows beyond 10MB in size.
> Each rotation belongs to a single container; if the container repeatedly fails or the pod is evicted, all previous rotations for the container are lost.
> **By default, Kubernetes keeps up to five logging rotations per container**.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. There's no file named `docker-containers` under my `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Did you check inside the container deployed by Kubernetes? I mean, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11046 shows: `/var/lib/docker/containers/63f0f01f331682d637413d0f550d22340a8ab0c6481205afe9823d53e2a2ee08# cat /etc/logrotate.d/docker-containers`

Comment: Hi @VonC thanks. There's no `etc` directory inside the container directory

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow OK. Any logrotate anywhere? I have always seen smaller logs because of that kind of service.

Comment: Hi @VonC thanks so much for the additional suggestion. There wasn't anything when I tried `crontab -l`, so I don't see where any lograte is being scheduled

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow I was more thinking about a service than a cron job. More generally, checking if there is any file/folder named `*logrotate*`.

Comment: no `find / *logrotate*` doesn't find anything